# Unable to understand the code properly in Ns2

Tags: ns2

1.why in below code why they used with 'at 11.5' and please explain me the details for the given NS2 code

```
$ns_ at 11.5 "source high-energy.tcl"

$ns_ at 13.5 "exec awk -f high-engy.awk Nodes-Initial-Energy Trace.tr Node-    cost-values"
$ns_ at 14.0 "exec awk -f Cluster-heads.awk clusterhead Node-cost-values"
$ns_ at 14.0 "source cluster-heads.tcl"
$ns_ at 14.3 "exec awk -f clusterhead-info.awk cluster-heads"
$ns_ at 14.3 "source comm.tcl"
$ns_ at 16.9 "exec awk -f Head-Ack.awk cluster-heads Nodes-Initial-Energy"
$ns_ at 16.9 "source communication1.tcl"
```

Answer (score 0):

---

`$ns_ at 11.5` ... means : "After 11.5 seconds do some action / command".

A similar time sequence is shown in the "Marc Greis, ns2 basics" http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript4.html , with an explanation.

---